# Get generic parameters from a ByReferenceType with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, cil, il, mono.cecil

I have a method which gets a parameter such as:

```
public void Foo(ref Action<string> bar);
```

Using Cecil to enumerate the parameters yields a ByReferenceType. Calling GetElementType() in an attempt to dereference the parameter returns a TypeReference with fullname:

```
System.Action`1
```

Somehow it has lost the generic parameters, and is no longer a GenericInstanceType.

How can I properly dereference the byref parameter, and get to the actual generic instance type?

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that's the notation used to indicate a generic method...

Comment: Yes, it is a generic method which accepts one generic parameter - but it provides no information about the type of the generic parameter.

Comment: A GenericInstanceType would yield a fullname such as System.Action`1<System.String>, and the first TypeReference object in the GenericParameters member would be that of System.String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dive into the TypeSpec using this (you can of course make it shorter when you know what you're after):

```
ParameterDefinition parameter = ...;
ByReferenceType byref = (ByReferenceType) parameter.ParameterType;
GenericInstanceType action_string = (GenericInstanceType) byref.ElementType;
TypeReference action = action_string.ElementType;
TypeReference str = action_string.GenericArguments [0];
```

The GetElementType method returns the original element type from which the TypeSpec is constructed.

Comment: I've tried something similar, with no luck:
(GenericInstanceType)(parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType()) => "Cannot cast 'parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType()' (which has an actual type of 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference') to 'Mono.Cecil.GenericInstanceType'"

Comment: @aethoric: This is not something similar. Use the ElementType property, not the GetElementType method. Admittedly, the naming could be better here, but ElementType returns the immediate predecessor in the type chain, and GetElementType returns the root type.